# filtering a column of string by list without doing exact match

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I am having a pandas data frame like below:-

```
    Tweets
0   RT @cizzorz: THE CHILLER TRAP *TEMPLE RUN* OBS...
1   Disco Domination receives a change in order to...
2   It's time for the Week 3 #FallSkirmish Trials!...
3   Dance your way to victory in the new Disco Dom...
4   Patch v6.02 is available now with a return fro...
5   Downtime for patch v6.02 has begun. Find out a...
6   ⛏️... soon
7   Launch into patch v6.02 Wednesday, October 10!...
8   Righteous Fury.\n\nThe Wukong and Dark Vanguar...
9   RT @wbgames: WB Games is happy to bring @Fortn...
```

I also have a list suppose like below :-

```
my_list = ['Launch', 'Dance', 'Issue']
```

with below command it filters out the dataframe :-

```
 ndata = data[data['Tweets'].str.contains( "|".join(my_list), regex=True)].reset_index(drop=True)
```

filter is not working if i am having

```
    Working        Not Working
    Launch        'launch' , 'launch,' , 'Launch,' ,'LAUNCH','@launch'
```

Expected output should be sentence havign any of the below word

```
'launch' , 'launch,' , 'Launch,' ,'LAUNCH','@launch'
```

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Comment: i edited the posted.... i hsould get the sentence in which it is having a word launch whether it is LAUNCH, Launch, launch or launch@ or launch,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that `contains` ignores the case:

```
import re

.
.
.

ndata = data[data['Tweets'].str.contains("|".join(my_list), regex=True,                          
                                         flags=re.IGNORECASE)].reset_index(drop=True)
#                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: thanks will it ignore the sopecial characters as well

Comment: @ak333 it will not "ignore" anything. If it finds one of the strings it will match. The problem is the case, not leading or trailing characters.

Comment: regex is by default `True` for `series.str.contains` and you can just use `flags=re.I` to save a bit of screenspace as most people reading it will know it's `IGNORECASE` anyway.